# Problems opening mp4 file with python

Tags: python, video

This code opens the video but it plays in slow-motion.

How can I fix this so the video can play normal speed?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Predicacion.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: opencv does not seem to be designed for that use-case (e.g. playing back full-hd h264 in real-time)!

Comment: You accepted an edit suggestion that changed the originally broken indentation to a different broken one. You don't have to accept edit suggestions if you disagree with them. And @yinnonsanders: please don't edit indentation in python questions, you can never know whether you're making the actual problem disappear. And of course _broken_ indentation edits are even less welcome.